# Did Yuddhiṣṭhira's feet never touch the ground?

Tags: mahabharata, yudhisthira

As discussed in [this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31444/chariot-of-yudhishthira-never-touched-the-ground-while-moving), Yuddhiṣṭhira was such a pious adherent of truth that his chariot never touched the ground. Well! not until he spoke a half-truth about Aśvatthāmā's death.

But, [some blogs](https://www.mahabharataonline.com/stories/mahabharata_character.php?id=59) maintain that even his feet didn't touch the ground.

> **Because of his piety, Yuddhiṣṭhira's feet and his chariot do not touch the
> ground, to symbolize his purity.**
>
> ....
>
> When he spoke his half-lie, Yuddhiṣṭhira's feet and chariot descended
> to the ground.

##### So, my question is, does this story occur in any recension of the Mahābhārata? Or is it just a folklore/hearsay tale only?

Comment: Highly Related, but not a duplicate of : [Chariot of Yudhishthira never touched the ground while moving?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31444/chariot-of-yudhishthira-never-touched-the-ground-while-moving)